# How can I access a iPhone's camera from a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, ios-camera

I created a web page for mobiles. I do not want to take a picture and upload it,  just open a web page and instantly open iPhone's camera.

I try to this code below but I still need to take a picture and upload images.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Please give me any suitable suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to directly access the phone's camera from a web page from within html5 as only native applications are given access to a device's camera. The closest you would be able to get would be to use something like [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/camera/camera.html) to create a native application which would have access to the camera.